# Use of curl command via HTTP

Tags: curl

Using curl command, how to transfer a file from one location to other via HTTP request?

Comment: what do you mean "one location" and "other"?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you use cURL to download a file that is available on a web server to your local machine.

For example, if I wanted to download the cURL source:

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.28.1.tar.gz -o curl-7.28.1.tar.gz
```

wget is another popular tool for doing this, and you don't need to specify an output file with -o:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.28.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple form is:

```
curl <url to retrieve>
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl is a command line utility for transferring data from or to a server designed to work without user interaction. With curl, you can download or upload data using one of the supported protocols including HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, and FTP.

Source : https://linuxize.com/post/curl-command-examples/

This is a curl request I use to send a .wav file (audio clip) to a remote server using Git Bash.

H is the header where I send an API SECRET which requires by my backend service. 
F is the audio file I send with the request.

```
curl \
    -H 'API_SECRET: eyJhiJIUzI19NiJ9._AKdgMbK-_en8' \
    -F "file=@myaudiofile.wav" \
    https://someurl/api/
```

Note :

1. Replace "someurl" with the api url to your backend service.
2. There has to be a file by the given name (in my case myaudiofile.wav) in the directory from where you execute the curl command.

I hope this helps.